# How do I compile this plugin?

Tags: makefile, gnu, automake, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm following the foo dissector example but would like to know how to compile it.

The foo dissector example is shown in this link:
http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChDissectAdd.html

You'll notice it mentions that the interlink directory contains good examples of support files I can use and that I need to modify Makefile.am & makefile.common etc.
I've modified those to reflect the foo module.

However, now I'd like to know how to build it.  I tried running automake but it complains there there is no configure.in.  Sorry I'm not too familar with the gnu build environment yet.

Also, is it possible to build this module standalone? or do I need all the other wireshark sources available?  I have of course installed wireshark-dev under ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Looks like I have to follow the instructions contained in the Wireshark source.
i.e. doc/README.plugins

Provides all the information required to build plugins for Wireshark.

Comment: Note that the wireshark build is a terrible example of how to use the autotools (or, perhaps it is an excellent example of how to completely butcher the autotools).  As a practical tip, you might want to completely avoid their bootstrap and just run autoreconf.  (That will construct configure.in and run automake for you.)

Comment: Care to explain what it *should* be doing with the autotools?

Comment: @WilliamPursell What exactly is wrong with the autotools configuration in Wireshark? Just the `autogen.sh` script, `configure.ac` or some of the `Makefile.am`s? Are the separate `Makefile.common` problematic according to you? (These are shared with the nmake files for Windows.)

Comment: Well, I haven't looked at Wireshark since 2009 or so, and I'm pretty sure they moved off the autotools long ago.  But, as I recall, they used a *lot* of boilerplate that would have been better performed in an m4 macro.  And they flagrantly violate a cardinal namespace rule, using the reserved names 'AC_*' for most, if not all, of the macros that they did define.  The name AC_WIRESHARK was common, but the prefix AC_ is to be used only by macros defined by autoconf itself.

Answer (score 5):

I went through README.plugins procedure and here what I've got:

1) Under plugins directory, rename

- Custom.m4.example to Custom.m4
- Custom.make.example to Custom.make
- Custom.nmake.example to Custom.nmake

2) Rename all of the foo occurrences in those files to your protocol name

3) Go to top-level wireshark directory and run autogen and configure as a root

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
```

Side Note: Make sure there is no warnings or errors during those steps. To compile your plugin properly copy following files from gryphon plugin to your newly created protocol folder along with source files and replace all gryphon occurrences with your protocol name

- AUTHORS
- COPYING
- ChangeLog
- CMakeLists.txt
- Makefile.am
- Makefile.common
- Makefile.in
- Makefile.nmake
- moduleinfo.h
- moduleinfo.nmake
- plugin.c
- plugin.rc.in

4) Compile plugins using following command. Run make install just in case

```
make -C plugins
make install
```

5) And finally run Wireshark with following command

```
WIRESHARK_RUN_FROM_BUILD_DIRECTORY=1 ./wireshark
```

6) If everything successful, you will see your plugin listed under About Wireshark, Plugins tab. I had some trouble with plugin version at first. Including following line after #include "config.h" fixed it:

```
#include "moduleinfo.h"
```